# Multiple Mic Inputs in Browser

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-app, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I am creating a web-based audio mixer to use in radio station and am trying to find a way to have multiple microphone inputs at the same time that are independently controllable. It only needs to work in one browser (firefox, chrome, ???) because we are going to be mainly using this in a localhost environment. Maybe someday we will make it available from a website, but only after the browsers get their acts together and choose one method for accomplishing this. I am working in a https environment.

I can use javascript to get one mic input, but it seems that if I choose a source for input then even if I have multiple tabs open with different audio experiments my choice moves with me from tab to tab.

I am not looking for someone to write my code, merely some pointing to experiments folks out there are running. I have been scouring the web for examples, but it seems that the browsers are changing the way this works all the time.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582017/recording-audio-from-multiple-microphones-simultaneously-with-getusermedia